# fetch the array element from nested mongo object

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following mongo document

```
    {
    "_id" : 1,
    "obj" : {
            "key..." : [
                    78,
                    23                      
            ],
            "key...." : [
                    134,
                    42,
                    78
            ],
            "key..." : [
                    141,
                    412,
                    341,
                    78
            ]
    }
```

}

i want get the 78 value where i don't know the key name present inside obj object

Comment: Are there always 4 elements in key array?

Comment: no the size will be any

Comment: `let arr = [];
Object.keys(obj['obj']).map(key => obj['obj'][key].map(function(item){
  if(item == 78) arr.push(`78 found in ${key}`)
}));`

Comment: Whilst it is *"possible"* to do something like `.find({   "$expr": { "$ne": [ { "$indexOfArray": [  { "$reduce": { "input": { "$objectToArray": "$obj" },          "initialValue": [], "in": { "$concatArrays": [ "$$value", "$$this.v" ]  }  }}, 78 ]}, -1 ]  } })` or even `.find({ "$where": "Object.keys(this.obj).reduce((o,k) => o.concat(this.obj[k]), []).indexOf(78) !=-1" })` you really should not. Computed expressions scan the whole collection. It's better to learn this is not a good design pattern for queries and change the data structure. Just like the linked answer says.